# Finding minimum value of word from a lot of files in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have 1000 `.txt` files on which I run this code. What I have to do is find the largest value of ENSG in the files and delete other values of ENSG which are less than the largest one. Then I have to find the minimum value from the same text file by looking at utr length and save it in my `output.txt` file. I want the output of 1000 `.txt` files in 1 `output.txt` file.  This code works approximately fine, but it overwrites the result. It only shows the result of last file:

```
import glob
f2 = glob.glob("./*.txt")
all_text=""
for fpath in f2:
    f = open(fpath,"r")
    list_lines = f.readlines()
    dic={}
    sent="ENSG"
    temp_list=[]
    for line in list_lines:
        all_text=all_text+line
        name= line.rsplit()[0].strip()
        score=line.rsplit()[1].strip()
        dic[name]=score
    for i in dic.keys():
        if sent in i:
            temp_list.append(dic[i])
            hiegh_score=max(temp_list)
    def check(index):
        reverse_text=all_text[index+1::-1]
        index2=reverse_text.find("\n")
        if sent==reverse_text[:index2+1][::-1][1:len(sent)+1]:
            return False
        else:
            return True

    list_to_min=dic.values()
    for i in temp_list:
        if i!=hiegh_score:
            index=all_text.find(str(i))
            while check(index):
                index=all_text.find(str(i),index+len(str(i)))
            all_text=all_text[0:index]+all_text[index+len(str(i)):]
            list_to_min.remove(str(i))
file2=open("my_try4.txt","w")
file2.write(all_text)
min_score= min(list_to_min)
for j in dic.keys():
    if min_score==dic[j]:
        k="min score is :"+str(min_score)+" for person "+j
        file2.write(k)
print "%6d : %s" % (len(list_lines),fpath)
file2.close()
f.close()
```

I have text files like this
`4.txt`:

```
ENSBTAG00000020679  197
ENSCAFG00000009872  2585
ENSG00000018236 1935
ENSG00000018236 230
ENSG00000018236 257
ENSG00000018236 338
ENSG00000018236 922
ENSG00000018236 922
ENSRNOG00000004438  14
ENSRNOG00000004438  14
```

Now it should select ENSG with 1935 and delete all other value of ENSG.  Now the text file should look like this:

```
    ENSBTAG00000020679  197
    ENSCAFG00000009872  2585
    ENSG00000018236 1935
    ENSRNOG00000004438  14
    ENSRNOG00000004438  14
```

And now, by looking at this text file, we find the shortest value and save it in a text file (We do this on 1000 files and output should be on 1 file).

```
output.txt
textfile4 14
```

Comment: http://hyperboleandahalf.blogspot.co.uk/2010/04/alot-is-better-than-you-at-everything.html Sorry, couldn't resist :)

Comment: Is your indentation right? You have your `open` in a loop and the `close` at the greatest scope.

Comment: Your question is difficult to understand and your code is even harder to understand. Could you rephrase? Why does it follow that "14" is selected? (What does "selected" mean here anyway?)  Do you want a set of the largest 'ENSG'-prefix value per file, and then the minimum value from that set of largest values?

Comment: @FrancisAvila I hope now you can understand my code and explanation

Comment: @FrancisAvila No , minimum value should not from the set of largest value of `ENSG` , its from the same text file from which we find the largest `ENSG` and delete all the other data of `ENSG` which have smaller values than the largest value and than find the minimum value from the remaining data and when we find the minimum value we save it to output file

Comment: Does "delete all other values" mean you want to modify the 4.txt file(s) (remove ESNG values), or are you referring to an in-memory structure?  And what is "`utr length`"?

Comment: Yes i want to modify the same txt files like 4.txt (Remove only ESNG values which are smaller than the largest , and largest remain in the 4.txt)

Comment: If more than one ENSG has the max value in a file, do you keep only one of them?

Comment: No , i want to keep both of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was easier to rewrite this than to figure out what was wrong with your code:

```
import os.path
import glob
import re
import itertools
from collections import namedtuple, deque
from operator import attrgetter

R_PREFIX_VALUE = re.compile(r'^(?P<prefix>[A-Z]+)(?P<suffix>\d+)\s+(?P<value>\d+)\s*$')

getvalue  = attrgetter('value')

def interleave(seq, val):
    return itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.izip(seq, itertools.repeat(val)))

class Fileline(namedtuple('Fileline', 'filename prefix suffix value')):
    @classmethod
    def _fromstr(cls, s, filename=None, rematch=R_PREFIX_VALUE.match):
        m = rematch(s)
        if not m:
            raise ValueError('No valid line found in %r' % s)
        d = m.groupdict()
        d['value'] = int(d['value'])
        d['filename'] = filename
        return cls(**d)

    def _asstr(self):
        return '{}{} {}'.format(self.prefix, self.suffix, self.value)

def max_value_with_prefix(lineseq, prefix, getvalue=getvalue):
    withprefix = (line for line in lineseq if line.prefix==prefix)
    return max_value(withprefix)

def filter_lt_line(lineseq, maxline):
    for line in lineseq:
        if line.prefix != maxline.prefix or line.value >= maxline.value:
            yield line

def extreme_value(fn, lineseq, getvalue=getvalue):
    try:
        return fn((l for l in lineseq if l is not None), key=getvalue)
    except ValueError:
        return None

def max_value(lineseq):
    return extreme_value(max, lineseq)

def min_value(lineseq):
    return extreme_value(min, lineseq)

def read_lines(fn, maker=Fileline._fromstr):
    with open(fn, 'rb') as f:
        return deque(maker(l, fn) for l in f)

def write_file(fn, lineseq):
    lines = (l._asstr() for l in lineseq)
    newlines = interleave(lines, '\n')
    with open(fn, 'wb') as f:
        f.writelines(newlines)

def write_output_file(fn, lineseq):
    lines = ("{} {}".format(l.filename, l.value) for l in lineseq)
    newlines = interleave(lines, "\n")
    with open(fn, 'wb') as f:
        f.writelines(newlines)

def filter_max_returning_min(fn, prefix):
    lineseq = read_lines(fn)
    maxvalue = max_value_with_prefix(lineseq, prefix)
    filteredlineseq = deque(filter_lt_line(lineseq, maxvalue))
    write_file(fn, filteredlineseq)
    minline = min_value(filteredlineseq)
    return minline

def main(fileglob, prefix, outputfile):
    minlines = []
    for fn in glob.iglob(fileglob):
        minlines.append(filter_max_returning_min(fn, prefix))
    write_output_file(outputfile, minlines)
```

The entry point is `main()`, which is called like `main('txtdir', 'ENSG', 'output.txt')`. For each file `filter_max_returning_min()` will open and rewrite the file and return the min value. There's no need to keep a dict or list of every line of every file you visited.

(BTW, destructively overwriting files seems like a bad idea! Have you considered copying them elsewhere?)

When you isolate separate concerns into separate functions, it becomes very easy to recompose them for different execution behavior. For example, it's trivial to run this task on all files in parallel by adding two small functions:

```
def _worker(args):
    return filter_max_returning_min(*args)

def multi_main(fileglob, prefix, outputfile, processes):
    from multiprocessing import Pool
    pool = Pool(processes=processes)
    workerargs = ((fn, prefix) for fn in glob.iglob(fileglob))
    minlines = pool.imap_unordered(_worker, workerargs, processes)
    write_file(outputfile, minlines)
```

Now you can start up a configurable number of workers, each of which will work on one file, and collect their min values when they are done.  If you have very large files or a great number of files and are not IO bound this might be faster.

Just for fun, you can also easily turn this into a CLI utility:

```
def _argparse():
    import argparse

    def positive_int(s):
        v = int(s)
        if v < 1:
            raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError('{:r} must be a positive integer'.format(s))
        return v

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter,
        description="""Filter text files and write min value.

    Performs these operations on the text files in supplied `filedir`:

    1. In each file, identify lines starting with the matching `maxprefix`
       which do *not* contain the maximum value for that prefix in that file.
    2. DESTRUCTIVELY REWRITE each file with lines found in step 1 removed!
    3. Write the minimum value (for all lines in all files) to `outputfile`.
    """)
    parser.add_argument('filedir',
        help="Directory containg the text files to process. WILL REWRITE FILES!")
    parser.add_argument('maxprefix', nargs="?", default="ENSG", 
        help="Line prefix which should have values less than max value removed in each file")
    parser.add_argument('outputfile', nargs="?", default="output.txt",
        help="File in which to write min value found. WILL REWRITE FILES!")
    parser.add_argument('-p', '--parallel', metavar="N", nargs="?", type=positive_int, const=10,
        help="Process files in parallel, with N workers. Default is to process a file at a time.")
    return parser.parse_args()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = _argparse()
    fileglob = os.path.join(args.filedir, '*.txt')
    prefix = args.maxprefix
    outputfile = args.outputfile
    if args.parallel:
        multi_main(fileglob, prefix, outputfile, args.parallel)
    else:
        main(fileglob, prefix, outputfile)
```

Now you can invoke it from the command line:

```
$ python ENSG.py txtdir ENSCAFG --parallel=4
```

Comment: You might want to explain it a bit more to bring it down to the OP's level of Python; also `int(s)` will raise `ValueError` if something non numeric is passed.

Comment: @Francis Avila I understand what you want to say , you adopt a good way to give me the understanding of how a programmer can write a good code , thank you for this , as your code seems more intelligent and easy than my coding

Comment: Doesn't seem like it found any files and so it recorded no minimum. Are your text files in `txtdir`?

Comment: @FrancisAvila Oah sorry for my last comments , actually there was problem with my dir's , but how i can read many file automatically , like `main('C:\\python27\\Dataset_splitting\\q4.txt', 'ENSG', 'output.txt')` what i give , and it only give output of q4 , but if i replace q4 with * it didnt work

Comment: As you can see in `def main()`, the first argument is a glob, so just pass `'dir_where_files_are/*.txt'`

Comment: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'prefix'` when i give my path `C:\python27\Dataset_splitting\*.txt` , my .py is in the same folder where i have text files

Comment: i run 2 files manually in it , why it overwrite the result of last output ? as i need the output of every text file

Comment: Your question sounded like you wanted the minimum among *all* files, not the minimum in *each* file. No matter, just collect all the minimums you find into a list. Doing this is a two or three line change to `main()`.

Comment: No , actually i want the minimum of each file , that's y i mention in my question that my program overwrite the result of last output

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26891/discussion-between-francis-avila-and-angel)